# How to edit multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables like this:

-artists 
-djs 
-track_artist 
-track_dj

I am adding two or more artists/djs while adding song via multiple select box. But I couldn't find how to edit those rows.

Adding song function:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO sarki (sarki_isim, sarki_tarz, sarki_file, sarki_resim, sarki_eklenmetarihi) VALUES (:isim, :tarz, :file, :resim, NOW())";
            $sqlartist = "INSERT INTO trackartist (trackartist_artist, trackartist_track) VALUES (:artistid, :trackid)";
            $sqldj = "INSERT INTO trackdj (trackdj_dj, trackdj_track) VALUES (:djid, :trackid)";

            try {
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array(':isim' => $b["isim"], ':tarz' => $b["tarz"], ':file' => $b["file"], ':resim' => $b["resim"]));
                $trackid = $this->db->lastInsertId();
                foreach ($b["artists"] as $artist) {
                    $insert = $this->db->prepare($sqlartist);
                    $insert->execute(array(":artistid" => $artist, ":trackid" => $trackid));
                }
                foreach ($b["djs"] as $artist) {
                    $insert = $this->db->prepare($sqldj);
                    $insert->execute(array(":djid" => $artist, ":trackid" => $trackid));
                }
                $db = null;
                return $stmt;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
```

Comment: Your code please...

Comment: adding codes right now

Comment: To "edit" rows in MySQL use the [UPDATE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Comment: @Kyoya I know I should use Update statement but I don't know how to edit multiple row. when I added a new song function creates multiple rows for artists and dj s . Above I added "adding new song function".